# Retrieving stored preferences in Java

Tags: java, preferences

The Preference `put` and `get` methods require and return string values, but I need to work with objects (colours), i.e.

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());

prefs.put("savedColour", "red");

Color c = prefs.get("savedColour", "black");
```

Obviously there's a type mismatch on that last line, but I can't store the actual colour in prefs either,

`prefs.put("savedColour", Color.RED)`

because you need to store it as a string (or int, but not colour).

Any solutions to this? Only thing that comes to mind is very messy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add a constructor to you `Color` class that takes a String and builds the `Color` instance.

```
public Color(String nameOfColor) {
  // do stuff
}
```

In addition you should implement the `toString()` method for the `Color` class.

Comment: I will look into this. I think it would probably be better to use RGB values, which are given in the toString() method (Color already has this method). But colour was just one of the many things that need saving for the preferences in this application, I'll see if it'll work for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

If essentially "serializing" the objects themselves is a requirement, perhaps using an alternate system to the Preferences API like [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) or [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) might be an option to "save" the objects to disk.

This would be more complex than just using the Preferences API, mind you, and if it's possble to store the object information as Tichodroma describes is possible I'd probably do that, but do you gain the increased flexibility of being able to represent the objects your interested in as more than just Strings.

You could even use it complementary to the Preferences API so that only the more complex objects are serialized, and the basics are kept in the Preferences format.

Comment: :-) I was just posting the same answer, pretty much, but you got in frist.

Comment: Seems to happen a lot around here!

Answer (score 0):

Convert color value into hexadecimal value and then store it as a string. While retrieving it decode hexadecimal value into string.

```
public static String getColorString(Color c) {
    int i = c.getRGB() & 0xFFFFFF;
    String s = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
    while (s.length() < 6) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}

public static void putColor(Preferences node, String key, Color c) {
    node.put(key, "0x" + getColorString(c));
}

public static Color getColor(Preferences node, String key, Color default_color) {
    Color result = default_color;
    String value = node.get(key, "unknown");
    if (!value.equals("unknown")) {
        try {
            result = Color.decode(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't decode color preference for '" + key + "' from '" + value + "'");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to store an object in your preferences, but it takes a few steps.  You can convert your object into a byte array, break it into pieces in a 2D byte array, then store the byte arrays into the slots of a single node.  Here is a step-by-step example on how to do it:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-prefapi/